# Passing Parameters to a Sitecore Sublayout

Tags: sitecore

I've done this before with a web control, but I can't seem to get it to work with a sublayout.  On the Presentation Details for a particular item I'm assigning my Sublayout and then in the additional parameters section specifying the parameter.  Here's the code that's in the code-behind for my sublayout.  When I run the debugger, RenderPageTitle is just null.

```cs
public partial class PageContent : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public String RenderPageTitle { get; set; }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RenderPageTitle.ToLower().Equals("false"))
        {
            TitleFieldRenderer.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do in the sublayout??

Comment: Selectively display a control in the sublayout based on the value of RenderPageTitle. I don't think it's relevant to the question, but I added the full code to hopefully help clear this up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

please refer to [this blog post](http://vapok.blogspot.com/2008/12/sitecore-6-using-parameters-in-web.html).

For sitecore6, in the .cs file:

```cs
string rawParameters = this.Parameters;
NameValueCollection parameters = Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.ParseUrlParameters(rawParameters);
```

or in .ascx file:

```cs
string rawParameters = Attributes["sc_parameters"];
NameValueCollection parameters = Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.ParseUrlParameters(rawParameters);
```

Answer (score 2):

There may be some better way to do this. It's hard to say.

The parameters to a sublayout are URL encoded (HttpUtility.UrlEncode or similar) and joined together like a querystring, and then placed in the "sc_parameters" attribute of the control.

So, like chiesa said, in a web user control (this is what that blog meant by .ascx file) you can do this:

```cs
string rawParameters = Attributes["sc_parameters"];
NameValueCollection parameters = 
  Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.ParseUrlParameters(rawParameters);
```

And then you have the parameters as a dictionary of strings. However, these are still encoded, so if they contain anything other than letters and numbers you will probably want to use something like HttpUtility.UrlDecode to fix them.

```cs
string color_scheme = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(parameters["ColorScheme"]);
int ash_diffuser_id = // Could have a + sign prepended or something.
  HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Int32.Parse(parameters["AshDiffuserID"]));
```

Comment: which namespace is 'Attributes' from ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have sublayout 's  parameter value by declaring _Param variable with NameValueCollection data type and refer tem to get the specific parameter value by passing the key value . This way this common function can reside into helper file and can be reused .

Here is the code snippet.

```
// All known parameters passed to the sublayout.
static NameValueCollection _params = null;

/// <summary>
/// Return the value of a specific parameter.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="key">Parameter name.</param>
/// <returns>Value of specified parameter.</returns>
public static string GetParam(string key)
{
    key.Trim().ToLower();
    string result = _params[key.Trim().ToLower()];

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
     {
          result = String.Empty;
     }

    return (System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(result));
}
```

You can get the value of the parameter that you passed in the sublayout simply by passing the key name of the parameter as an argument of this function .

Hope this helps .